# Jump from one step to another in SharePoint workflow 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am using Sharepoint designer 2010 to develop workflow. At some point to avoid code duplication, I want to jump from one step to another in workflow. 
Is it possible?

I searched lot on google but no luck. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not available to jump between steps in SharePoint 2010 workflow via SharePoint Designer, you can only create a sequential workflow that runs step by step without transition.

To can achieve that you should

- Handle your workflow steps in a single step and manage transition via `if condition`. it's not a practical solution but maybe work if your workflow is small.
- Use visual studio to develop your workflow.

**FYI** SharePoint 2013 workflow platform introduce a `transition to stage` that allows the transition (jump) from one stage to another based on your business need.